# How to check whether the cstore FDW is present on a citus build of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, psql, foreign-data-wrapper, citus

I am running citus PostgreSQL build from here:

https://github.com/citusdata/docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

But I don't know how to check whether the instance has the cstore foreign data wrapper available for columnar support? I'm guessing there's a way to do it from psql much like HSTORE?

Comment: `pg_available_extensions` and `pg_extensions` ?

Comment: You can query the catalog tables, like Craig suggested, or just run the `create extension` command & see what happens. There is also a [FDW, which can list other FDWs](https://github.com/daamien/fdw_fdw), but if want to find out that this FDW is available or not, that will be tricky (if not philosophical)

Comment: If one of you want to make that an answer, I'll mark it answered. Thanks!